# tmp is not ready error

Tags: tmp

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 from external hard-drive. Sometimes, when I run ubuntu "the disk drive for /tmp is not ready" error message appears and OS cannot be started. In this case, I restart several times to open ubuntu. Is there way to eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this on a normal machine would be to add `/tmp` to `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults            0       0
```

But there was a [fix for mountall for 13.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792). If you do have this it could be the external disk is just too slow.